# Block facebook even in the case users get their hands on tor, freegate and similar applications

Tags: content-filter, ip-blocking, tor

I've been using, happily, opendns to block facebook on my network.
Then I started thinking about tricks to circumvent this block and, of course, I've read here on serverfault how to block the facebook ip address.
But if someone uses tor or freegate?

What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like you need a policy of "use tor and you're toast". ... With more friendly sounding wording maybe.

Comment: It's worth asking: why block Facebook at all? Of course there are circumstances where it's appropriate, but I'd suggest they're the exception rather than the rule. Despite all evidence to the contrary, people are smart. Those who want to avoid work will find a way to do so with or without Facebook. The measure of an employee should be their quality and quantity of work, not how much time they spend on things you consider distractions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you have isn't really a technical problem, it's a management problem, don't try to make it a technical problem. You need to have an acceptable use policy that clearly defines what users can and can't do with the resources provided by your organisation. This should also detail what steps may be taken to enforce the AUP (monitoring usage/auditing machines etc) and what the sanctions for breaking the AUP are.

Comment: +1 (or more).  Trust your users, treat them like adults, and trust them not to take the piss, and they probably won't.  If you don't trust your staff, why did you hire them?

Comment: The only problem is when the "management problem" is thrust on IT's lap, because management believes that it is a technical problem. Nothing that can be said will convince them otherwise, and you are forced to find some way to block site X.  Having an AUP is not a barrier or deterrent to some people, and when their management does not enforce the AUP, you are left picking up the pieces.  I do not believe in blocking the sites, but the people who run the company I work for do.

Comment: @Buggabill ... and in that case you *allow* the sites and set up a script to forward a message to the Person In Charge on the floor who is tasked with enforcing the AUP - nothing's *technically* stopping the users from doing what they're not supposed to, a manager just magically appears...

Comment: So if you don't really agree with the blocking of Facebook, don't tie yourself in knots trying to close the edge case loopholes unless you are asked to.  I am sure the management will be happy with a block that prevents 99% of users from visiting the sites they are worre

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to ask Why you are trying to block Facebook?  I'm assuming this is a corporate network not home.  Why should you allow your staff to use myspace, twitter and amazon, friends-reunited etc but not Facebook?
This sort of corporate content filtering (the organisation I work for does this as well) is almost always pointless.  It tries to block websites it considers rude.  Why? I'm a grown-up (most of the time), I can deal with rude words.  My org tries to block webmail to prevent us e-mailing information home, but it doesn't block my ntl webmail becuase the person setting up the rules didn't think of it.  Nor does it block my personal webmail server.
I'm all in favour of companies monitoring the web usage of staff, and having management policies in place to say what is considered acceptable web usage, both work related and personal.  But the automated blocking of sites is annoying (especially in the case of a false positive) and is ultimatly not actually going to prevent anything significant.  Save yourself the hassle, make sure the proxy virus scans content and downloads and that your firewall is configured well, leave the policing your users internet habits to their managers.

Comment: There was a facebook-related question that seemed related to a problem I was having on SO and my company's policy blocked it. >_<

Answer (score 5):

The harder you try to block it, the harder the users will try to get access to it.

Comment: I agree, it's dangerous to have frustrated and angry users.

Answer (score 3):

> What can I do?

The old-fashioned means for enforcing similar "productivity policies" remains: get managers watching over employees' shoulders whenever a TPS report is late (or the wrong cover sheet is used).

Comment: +1 When productivity slips, figure out why. If they're productive, who cares how they get it done?

Comment: It's always those damn cover sheets for the TPS reports, that gets me ;)

Answer (score 3):

Well, for starters (beyond what everyone else said about policy and governance), you should be blocking egress traffic on your network outside of what's required (and I generally don't allow client machines to make direct TCP/UDP connections anywhere; there's no need 99% of the time when you have a proxy server in-house), especially UDP/TCP 53 to outside DNS servers.

I've used Layer 3 filtering and OpenDNS together with alot of success at clients (such as yours) that are not treating this like a management problem (which it is).  However, if they want to pay me to come in and set this up after explaining that then so be it.

Even better than dropping outbound DNS would be to setup a proxy server (Squid is open source/free and does a good job caching as well; depending on your size, aging workstation hardware is likely fine).

Now you can drop all direct TCP/UDP connections from the clients to the outside and force everyone to use a proxy (transparently, and they won't even notice).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the next step would be to look at Facebook's URL's, headers or data. Just make sure whatever filtering you use (Squid is an example) doesn't affect the `Like' button, since many popular sites implement that now. To be honest, there isn't really a way to stop a user if they have some form of tunnel or VPN running.

Comment: I've used firewalls to filter on !id=\"facebook\"! with much success.

Answer (score 2):

First off, do you have a policy, backed at a high level, that forbids Facebook?  If not, then  you may be treading on the toes of your boss, or their boss, who actually want to use Facebook.   Many companies are happy to accept reasonable levels of social network use at work anyway, and view an all out block as counter productive.  I'll assume there is a banning policy in place though.

If you worry about circumvention then you'll need to start investigating blocking Tor or Freegate, and then the next thing and the thing after that - but I'd advise monitoring your network for evidence that these, or other circumvention techniques are in use, and a friendly word in the ear of the guilty party on first instance, and their manager on the second.  Usually just letting someone know you can tell what they are up to is enough to get it under control.

Anyone with the smarts to use Tor or other "clever" ways around should also be smart enough to use Facebook on their mobile phone, which you can't block.

Comment: Cell jammers exist - they don't comply to FCC regulations (obviously) but the most draconian of corporate IT departments is probably already irradiating their staff with 'em.

Comment: I imagine that Blackberry and corporate cell phone use would limit the number of these that are in place in the corporate environment - and seems like total overkill to prevent staff checking Facebook.

Comment: I'd put my money on the fact that the "no Facebook" policy's enforcement begins and ends at the call center/sales floor.

Answer (score 2):

The [Barracuda Web Filter](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/spyware_overview.php) is convenient for this. There are recent options to disable proxying applications and workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Don't close it fully! Just make a "happy hour" when users can use any social network they want facebook, hi5 etc, so that they will know that f.example at 14.00 when  they can make a cofee break, eat donuts and check what's going on and be social. and they will not think to break the system. Otherwise they will do it hidden and all day long... 
Dont forget that anyway they can go in with mobiles and 3g which you cannot close. 
Cheerz.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW,

my company doesn't require us to block any social networking sites, and we have zero problems with users spending too much time on them. I completely agree with the "treat them like adults" mindset.